# setting li to active when clicked [codeigniter]

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter. My problem is that, when I set the `li >a` to `active` it doesn't reflect the changes. I have this code:

```
$('.nav li > a').click(function() {
    $('.nav li').removeClass();
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

The structure of my program: Every click in the link the header always been loaded.

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active" style="margin-left: 20px"><a href="<?php echo site_url('Account/viewAccounts');?>">Manage Accounts</a></li>
                <li style="margin-left: 10px"><a href="<?php echo site_url('User/viewUser');?>">View Users</a></li>
                <li style="margin-left: 531px"><a href="<?php echo site_url('logout');?>"> Log out <i style="margin-left:5px" class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Sample Controller:

```
public function viewAccounts(){

        $this->load->model('user_model'); 
        $data['users']=$this->user_model->getAllAccounts(); 
         $this->load->view('include/header');
         $this->load->view('admin/viewAccounts',$data); 
         $this->load->view('include/footer');

}
```

Comment: Can we see your HTML too?

Comment: it's working here check. http://jsfiddle.net/eua4noto/

Comment: Your html structure also working check: http://jsfiddle.net/eua4noto/1/ .

Comment: have you add active css class?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eua4noto/4/

Comment: @Rasel it doesn't work on me because everytime I click a link, the header is loaded.

Comment: even when return false added?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$('.nav li a').click(function() {
    $('ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

**or**

```
$('.nav li a').click(function() {
    $('ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `active` as parameter to `removeClass`

```
$('.nav li').on('click', 'a', function() {
    $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
    //                        ^^^^^^
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');

    return false; // To stop redirection
});
```

Comment: It worked just for the interface but not for the functionality.

Comment: @d_unknown Try `closest` as in answer

Answer (score 0):

since every time you click on those its going to reload the page. and the active page cann't be tracked in the front end. It has to be done in the php code.
follow the https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html to get the right segment and use `<?=($this->uri->segment(1)==='Account/viewAccounts')?'active':''?>` this add the `active` class name to the right list.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li class="<?=($this->uri->segment(1)==='Account/viewAccounts')?'active':''?>" style="margin-left: 20px"><a href="<?php echo site_url('Account/viewAccounts');?>">Manage Accounts</a></li>
   <li class="<?=($this->uri->segment(1)==='User/viewUser')?'active':''?>" style="margin-left: 10px"><a href="<?php echo site_url('User/viewUser');?>">View Users</a></li>
   <li class="<?=($this->uri->segment(1)==='logout')?'active':''?>" style="margin-left: 531px"><a href="<?php echo site_url('logout');?>"> Log out <i style="margin-left:5px" class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> </a></li>
</ul>
```

for more you can refer [CodeIgniter: How to 'highlight' the link of the page the user is currently on?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3357371/)

### Below is the pure javascript answer

The `.removeClass()` method takes a *class name* or *function* as argument and missed it

refer: https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

Here is a working example

```js
$('.nav li > a').click(function() {
  $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active a {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Manage Accounts</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">View Users</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> Log out <i style="margin-left:5px" class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> </a>
        </li>
      </ul>



    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post back the updated code and the only mistake you did was missing the *class_name* argument for `.removeClass()` and if possible plz provide live site url.

Comment: @d_unknown I've updated the answer in both php and JavaScript