# Manage or Highlight Active link or page in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I know this question comes across a lot, but I just can't figure out how to do this using the, already answered posts.
this is my view page

```
<<li class="active"> <a class="page-scroll" href="<?php echo base_url();?>nowaste_control/index#about">Home</a> </li>
    <li ><a class="page-scroll" href="<?php echo site_url('nowaste_control/index#product'); ?>">Products</a> </li>
    <li > <a class="page-scroll" href="<?php echo base_url();?>nowaste_control/index#technology">Technology</a> </li>
```

this is my jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
  $('a[href="'+window.location.pathname+window.location.hash+'"]').parent().addClass('active');
 });
</script>
```

my path is this->localhost/nowaste/nowaste_control/index#about

here all of the pages is getting active...

Comment: echo $this->uri->segment(1); check your condition is matched or not

Comment: What does return `$this->uri->segment(1)` ?

Comment: its returning nowaste

Comment: Refer here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357371/codeigniter-how-to-highlight-the-link-of-the-page-the-user-is-currently-on Did you add the Helper file for menu

Comment: i using hash fragment here thats why iam not getting

Answer (score 0):

You actually have URL's with multiple segments but only ever compare the first. The `segment()` is popping off the array only the first array part. This means you're only ever getting `nowaste_control` and never `index`.

What you actually want is `$this->uri->uri_string()` which will give you the entire unaltered string.

This poses another problem in that your links are using the `hash fragment` (#), however, codeigniter will never observe this in a URL request because Apache is not going to receive this in the request, it's only for the client side.

So what you actually need is a JavaScript solution. Here's one with jQuery that just works.

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('a[href="'+window.location.pathname+window.location.hash+'"]').parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: what changes is to be made to view page

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery maybe you can do something like this by handling it at client side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      alert("Current Pathname:" + window.location.pathname);
      if(window.location.pathname=="some path"){
        $("#someLi").addClass("active");
      }else if(window.location.pathname=="some other path"){
        //..
      }
    });

</script>
```